# How to show a spelling error suggestions popup on mouse over a WPF TextBox with spell checking enabled in Winforms C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using element host to use WPF spell checker textbox in my winforms.

I want to override the context menu that appears on misspelled red squiggles to `mouse hover` instead of `right click.`

How to do that?
Tried overriding the behavior but it is still the same:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
class SpellCheck: ElementHost 
{
    privated TextBox box;

    public SpellCheck()
    {
        box = new TextBox();
        base.Child = box;
        box.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        box.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;                    
    } 

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Multiline
    {
        //checks for multiline
    }

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
       //checks for spell check enabled or not
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool WordWrap
    {
        //does wordwraps
    }

    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public int MaxLength
    {
        //maxlength property
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new System.Windows.UIElement Child
    {
        get { return base.Child; }
        set { }
    }

}
```

It shows spell suggestions on right click. I want to change it to Mouse hover or any other mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TextBox.PreviewMouseMove` to show a popup to achieve this.
You also need to create a new `Form` to serve as a popup. This `Form` could contain a `FlowLayoutPanel` to host the suggestions. In this example the `Form` is named `CustomPopup`:

```
box.PreviewMouseMove += OpenContextMenuOnMouseMove;
```

The event handler for `TextBox.PreviewMouseMove`:

```
private void OpenContextMenuOnMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
{
  var textBox = sender as System.Windows.Controls.TextBox;

  var mouseOverTextIndex = textBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(textBox), false);

  // Pointer is not over text
  if (mouseOverTextIndex.Equals(-1))
  {
    return;
  }

  int spellingErrorIndex = textBox.GetNextSpellingErrorCharacterIndex(mouseOverTextIndex, LogicalDirection.Forward);

  // No spelling errors
  if (spellingErrorIndex.Equals(-1))
  {
    return;
  }

  int startOfWordIndex = mouseOverTextIndex;
  while (startOfWordIndex != -1 && !textBox.Text[startOfWordIndex].Equals(' '))
  {
    startOfWordIndex--;
  }

  var endOfWordIndex = textBox.Text.IndexOf(" ", mouseOverTextIndex, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  if (endOfWordIndex.Equals(-1))
  {
    endOfWordIndex = textBox.Text.Length - 1;
  }

  //  Spelling error doesn't belong to current mouse over word
  if (spellingErrorIndex < startOfWordIndex || spellingErrorIndex > endOfWordIndex)
  {
    return;
  }

  using(CustomPopup popup = new CustomPopup())
  {
    // Create clickable suggestions for the CustomPopup.
    foreach (var suggestion in textBox.GetSpellingError(spellingErrorIndex).Suggestions)
    {
      // Each Button represents a suggestion.
      var suggestionButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button() { Text = suggestion };

      var fixSpellingErrorEventArgs = new FixSpellingErrorEventArgs()
      {
        TargetTextBox = textBox,
        WordStartIndex = startOfWordIndex,
        WordEndIndex = endOfWordIndex,
        Suggestion = suggestion
      };

      // The Button.Click callback will apply the selected fix
      suggestionButton.Click += (s, e) => FixSpellingError_OnButtonClicked(fixSpellingErrorEventArgs);

      // TODO::Replace the line with a public member of CustomPopup Form: CustomPopup.AddPanelContent(Control):void.
      // e.g. public void AddPanelContent(Control control) { this.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(suggestionButton); }
      // and use it like: popup.AddPanelContent(suggestionButton);
      popup.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(suggestionButton);
    } 

    popup.SetDesktopLocation((int) mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(textBox).X, (int) mouseEventArgs.GetPosition(textBox).Y);

    popup.ShowDialog(this);
  }
}

// The event handler that applies the selected fix.
// Invoked on popup button clicked.
private void FixSpellingError_OnButtonClicked(FixSpellingErrorEventArgs e)
{
  // Select misspelled word and replace it with the selected fix
  e.TargetTextBox.SelectionStart = e.WordStartIndex;
  e.TargetTextBox.SelectionLength = e.WordEndIndex - e.WordStartIndex;
  e.TargetTextBox.SelectedText = e.Suggestion;
}
```

The custom event arg object for Button.Click event

```
class FixSpellingErrorEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  public System.Windows.Controls.TextBox TargetTextBox { get; set; }
  public int WordStartIndex { get; set; }
  public int WordEndIndex { get; set; }
  public string Suggestion { get; set; }
}
```

To enhance the example create the logic how or when the popup will disappear (time out and focus lost?).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197452/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-how-to-show-a-spelling-error-suggestions-popu).